# DataBind() before inserting data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Why in code below the `DataBind()` "works" only before the `Insert()`

Working code:

```
DataView dvTransportadora = dtTransportadora.DefaultView;
dvTransportadora.Sort = "NICKNAME ASC";

ddlTransportadora.DataSource = dvTransportadora;
ddlTransportadora.DataValueField = "ID_CUSTOMER";
ddlTransportadora.DataTextField = "NICKNAME";
ddlTransportadora.DataBind();

ListItem lstItmSelecione = new ListItem("SELECT", "0");
ddlTransportadora.Items.Insert(0, lstItmSelecione);
```

Not Working code:

```
DataView dvTransportadora = dtTransportadora.DefaultView;
dvTransportadora.Sort = "NICKNAME ASC";

ddlTransportadora.DataSource = dvTransportadora;
ddlTransportadora.DataValueField = "ID_CUSTOMER";
ddlTransportadora.DataTextField = "NICKNAME";

ListItem lstItmSelecione = new ListItem("SELECT", "0");
ddlTransportadora.Items.Insert(0, lstItmSelecione);

ddlTransportadora.DataBind();
```

In "not working code" the item "SELECT" doesn't appear, the DataBind() doesn't must to refresh the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 3):

When you bind the data it will clear out all of the items currently in the collection and make new ones for each new item in the data source.

You either need to add the additional item to the underlying data source, rather than inserting it into the control itself, or you need to do what you did in your first example and bind the data before inserting any items directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you DataBind you are effectively removing what was there previously because you are setting the DataSource. You can add to the list once you have bound to data however. It just might not be there next time you refresh.

To prevent the new values being overwritten you could add to the Data Source directly. For example, assuming the control is bound to a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) you could call the AddNew method. If the data is coming from a database you need to add the new value to the database and then call DataBind again, or do whatever is necessary depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The DataBind() "works" only before the Insert(), Because the DataBind() will clear all your data in dropdownlist and add all data in your datasource. So anything you insert before databind will remove or clear.

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownList is a ListControl and all ListControls have a property called AppendDataBoundItems (which defaults to false). If you set this property to true, any items that will be created because of a DataBind() call will not first clear the already existing items, but will append them to the list. Your own item should not be cleared in that case.